# Need to find components of a vector given distance and angle from a known vector on a known plane

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]I am looking for a way to compute the components  of a vector (C in illustration) given: components  of A and B, the angle between B and C, and the magnitude of C. I am looking for a way to solve this in a general case, where A,B, and C are coplanar.

I have tried getting these values by rearranging and/or combining several vector identities, but I can't seam to get anything. I feel like there should be a simple solution to this that I just don't see. I was thinking that if I defined a plane ax+by+cz=d with A x B I could somehow plug in |c|^2 = ^2 + ^2 + ^2 and dot product(B,C) = |C| * |B| * cos(θ) but I have not found a solution for that. To clarify this is in (x,y,z) coordinates and I am looking for a formula that I can fit into an algorithm, not a specific case solution.

Comment: HINT: projection of C onto B (but scalar or vector)?

Comment: The answer is not unique. The tip of C could be any where on the edge of base of a cone.

Comment: Jossie, by projection of C on B do you mean dot product? I've tried rearranging several vector identities in attempt to get values for the vector component of C and I cannot seem to figure out how (I'm probably over complicating it).

Comment: Maesumi, the vectors are coplanar.